# Google OAuth JWT signature verification

Tags: php, validation, google-oauth, jwt

I'm making my own google oauth implementation in PHP project. Everything works fine unless I'm trying to verify `JWT` received after the **access token** request (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token).

For JWT decoding I'm using [**firebase/php-jwt**](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) class.

It decodes perfectly, but if I switch on `$verify` option (`decode()` method 3-rd arg) I get : `Signature verification failed` exception thrown.

My guess is that, if I pass a wrong key to the `decode()` method. It's used later for `hash_hmac()` function when signature is generating done.

So my question is: What key exactly should I pass for signature verification to the Google OAuth JWT context?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#validatinganidtoken the recommended approach:

"we recommend that you retrieve Google’s public keys from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs and perform the validation locally.

Since Google changes its public keys only infrequently (on the order of once per day), you can cache them and, in the vast majority of cases, perform local validation much more efficiently than by using the TokenInfo endpoint. This requires retrieving and parsing certificates, and making the appropriate crypto calls to check the signature. Fortunately, there are well-debugged libraries available in a wide variety of languages to accomplish this."

Comment: Note that I had two Google certificates return and needed to attempt a verify with each in a try/catch.

Comment: @AramKocharyan you shouldn't. jwt header has "kid" field which identifies public key.